# Android App that communicate whith Skype

Tags: android, skype

I try to developp an Android App that answer automatically a call Skype.
I already visited this link http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri, it helped me to initaite a call from my application.
The probleme that faces me is: I can't know if Skype mobile sends out a public broadcast on such events (which would be the usual way to be programmatically notified of incoming messages). Because I tried to listen events by BroadCastReceveir and I didn't receive any things from Skype.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.